# Sign Xml with digital certificate in format of PKCS#7 in DER (ITU-T Rec. X.690)

Tags: c#, digital-signature, pkcs#7, pfx

I have a `.xml` file that has to be signed with `digital certificate` in format of `PKCS#7 version 1.5 (RFC 2315)` and `DER (ITU-T Recommendation X.690`

That `.xml` will be send to a govt. `WebService` that only accept the format I mentioned upwards.

What I'm able to do - thanks to [this website](http://rooseboom.net/?p=23) is digitaly sign `.xml` with the `.pfx` file that I generated with `Certificate Export Wizard` explained below. The class that I'm using to sign is down on mentioned website or [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5phooctpyc6b0gw/b8hIFORKFJ/XmlDsig.cs).

From what I tried to understand so far I will need to sign the `.xml` with `.pfx` file according to `X.690` standards but I'm only able to access this namespace:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
```

which is obviously for X.509 format.

Note:

There are several things I'm confused about - to export the certificate into `.pfx` I'm using `Internet Explorer - Certificate Export Wizard` from there I'm able to:

Yes - export private keys - then it will be generated in `PKCS#12` but `.pfx`

No - do not export private keys - Certificate according to standards `Cryptographic Message Syntax Standard - PKCS#7` that I guess I need but I would receive `.p7b` file

I must say that I am a newbie in certificates and digital signatures so I'm not even sure if I'm correctly exporting the certificat and the second thing is how I can sign according to `X.690` standards.

May I know how to sign according to X.690 format please?

Thank you everyone for your time and replies.

My code is following:

```
bool res = false;
try
{
    byte[] certBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pvkPath);
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, certPass);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(xmlPath);

    // sign the document with the private key of the certificate
    XmlDsig.SignXml(doc, cert);

    // save the document
    doc.Save(xmlSavePath);

    // verify that the document has a signature
    bool hasSignature = XmlDsig.HasSignatureElement(doc);
    return res = true;
}
catch (Exception)
{ return res; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foDigital signature in PKCS#7/CMS format is blob that contains your XML data + signer's x509 public key certificate (.cer file) + Digital signature. The entire blob is encoded in ASN 1.0 format(X690). There may be variations in the blob due to the absence of original data or the signer certificate, This variation is called detached signatures.

Digital signature is generated when you sign your xml file with the signer's private key. This signature can be verified when you send your XML file + signer's public key (as X509 .cer file)+ digital signature to the party who are interested in verifying it.

PFX/p12 is a container that contains both the signer's private key and public key. You get this key pair from either your government or your government approved key custodians. You will then use this PFX to perform digital signature.

PKCS#7 is supported by [cryptoAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa380252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#message_functions).

The above are the basics. This should allow you make your queries more clearly.

Comment: Hello, thanks alot for your answer that cleared out the whole procedure. I have tried for last 2 days to digitally sign the XML with private key of the `.pfx` file so I generated new `file.xml.p7m` file which according to you is the one of two parts that I need to send - do I need to attach the public key to it? Thank you again so much.

Comment: PKCS#7 format is already defined. Many APIs support this. One of them is CryptoAPI, others are OpenSSL, BountyCastle. What API are you using to sign your file? Your API will allow you attach the Public key certificate.

Comment: Weel I'm using `BouncyCastle` The code I have so far is here https://gist.github.com/mareksip/3d4ac5e72e35adeada21 it generates `.p7b` file that has 1 kB. but the original `.xml` file that has to be send according to pkcs7 has 5 kB. Thanks alot for your advices.

Comment: The following should help you. http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jonah/bc/org/bouncycastle/jce/PKCS7SignedData.html